# How to dynamically obtain JQuery values to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

new week, new problems with my project, so I'll be glad to see any suggested solutions of yours :) .

The obstacle consists in that I have a slider made up with jQuery UI and I also have a JavaScript function which needs to get jQ's values of slider's increase and respectively decrease and store it in a variable.
So far, I was able to make a slider and stream it's parameters to an html `<p><span>`.. construction but it's not enough because this reflects only on the output of the document and has nothing to do with my js code/functions which I'm planning to develop later. Up to now, my code looks something like this:

```
 $(function(){
  $(".slider").slider()
  $("#angle").slider({
    value:0,
    min:0,
    max:250,
    step:0.5,
    slide: function (event, ui){
       $( "#angres" ).html( ui.value );
       $("fang").change(function(){
        $("ang").val($(this).val());
       });
      }
    });
   $("#angres").html($('#angle').slider('value'));
```

Ok, this $( "#angres" ).html( ui.value ); works absolutely fine and displays the 'movement' of the slider on the document, with a changing value. However, I need to have exactly the same value in a parameter, to use it with js. I need to store this change in a variable. How to do it? :)

Comment: `$(".slider").slider()` shoud end with `;`

Comment: @Reflective Most of the time `;` are optional in JS.

Comment: Probably you are a trouble-lover if you prefer to avoid the correct syntax. You should be aware of tha fact that your code is executed client side which means different browsers, different OS, different devices and other different things that you could even not imagine :)

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking for help with.  The slider can be configured to call a function anytime the slider value changes.  You hook in your own callback for that and then you can do anything you want from that callback.  What are you asking?

Comment: The concept, "connecting jQuery with JavaScript" doesn't make a lot of sense; jQuery **is** JavaScript. It's really not clear what it is you want to do.

Comment: @Reflective Comma insertion is a rigorously-specified aspect of JavaScript syntax. It does not vary among implementations in modern environments.

Comment: Comma? I was talking about semicolon ';' and generally about the fact that a programmer can only have benefit following the correct syntax, even sometimes it could be avoided ...

Comment: @Reflective oops sorry I meant semicolon :)  I'm low on caffeine or something I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about assignig a variable to the global window scope.
Modify it inside your slider (increase, decrease, whatever)
Any other "JS" (jQuery *is* JavaScript) function will be able, on call, to read that variable value (*state*)

```
var counter = 0; // Global variable

function getCounterValue() {
    alert( counter );      // Will always give you the modified `counter` value
}
// Call the above function wherever you want

jQuery(function($) { // jQuery. DOM ready

     // Slider >> increment `counter`, decrement `counter`...
     // ...other super jQuery DOM ready stuff
});
```

Comment: I will just suggest to store the value as data in the related tag which will keep the globality but the value will be stored in a related to the purpose place.